Want to use the input values at the time of custom installation to be used in the application made in VB.net
I am programming in VB.net . I have made setup project to custom install my main application and added Textbox (A) dialog in user interface. At the time of installation, I want the input of the textbox (A) dialog to be saved as string and want those values to be used by the application as a Variable/Constant everytime it runs after installation
So far I have tried this in installer project:
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class Installer1
    Inherits Installer

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Dim userinput As String

    Public Overrides Sub Install(stateSaver As IDictionary)
         MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
         userinput = Context.Parameters("UserInput") 'CustomActionData = /UserInput=[EDITA1]
                                                     'this is set in custom action property

         stateSaver.Add("UserInput", userinput)
         My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Installer1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles_
    Me.AfterInstall
    
        MessageBox.Show("This is working " + userinput)  'This is added to confirm that the user
                                                         'input in Textbox (A) has been converted
                                                         'to string userinput                        

    End Sub

So at the end of installation msgbox appears with the text of textbox that I entered in the dialog at the time of installation. So I think i am right upto this.
Now I am not able to retrieve this userinput value when I run the application after installation to dispaly in a textbox.
Which code to write to use this userinput string value in windows application form project to display it in a textbox (TextBoxInput)

A file would be an obvious choice.

My.Settings is surprisingly bad for holding user settings. I would recommend writing a JSON file to the user's appdata folder.

I would recommend saving your settings in a JSON file in the %appdata% folder.
Create a settings class containing your settings, with shared Save and Load methods:
Imports System.Text.Json
Public Class SettingsClass
  Public Property SettingValue1 As String
  Public Property SettingValue2 As Integer
  Public Property SettingArray3 As String()

  Public Shared Sub Save(settings As SettingsClass, filename As String)
    Dim s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, s)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Function Load(filename) As SettingsClass
    Dim s = IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)
    Return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of SettingsClass)(s)
  End Function
End Class

Then use those Save and Load methods to store your settings and load them back:
Imports System

Module Program
  Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) 'different for each user on this PC
    'Dim programDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) 'same for all users on this PC
    Dim settingsFilename = IO.Path.Combine(appDataFolder,  "junkSettings.json")

    Dim mySettings = New SettingsClass With {.SettingValue1 = "Setting1", .SettingValue2 = 123, .SettingArray3 = {"a", "b", "c"}}

    SettingsClass.Save(mySettings, settingsFilename)

    Dim mySettings2 = SettingsClass.Load(settingsFilename)
    Console.WriteLine(mySettings2.SettingValue1)

    Console.WriteLine("Finished")
  End Sub
End Module

You can type %appdata% in Windows File Explorer to see the file.
